# Circular Single Linked List C++ Delete Problem

Tags: c++

I want to remove one node from a Circular Single Linked List and when i reach to the Cmd, it shows me an address (maybe) which is repeating infintely. Please help me or show me what is wrong. Here is the code in C++

```
using namespace std;
class Node{
private:
    int data;
    Node * next;
public:
    void setdata(int s);
    int getdata()
    {
        return data;
    }
    void setnext(Node * next_pointer);
    Node * getnext();
};
void Node::setdata(int s){
    data = s;
    }
Node * Node::getnext(){

return this->next;
}
void Node::setnext(Node *next_node)
{
        this->next = next_node;
}
class Circular{
private:
    Node * first;
    int sizen;
public:
    Circular();
    void append(int value);
    void display();
    Node * walk(int start, int die=3);
    int remove_node(Node * prev_node);
    int getsize();
    Node * get_first();
    void removing(int val);
};
Circular::Circular(){
first = 0;
sizen = 0;
}
void Circular::append(int val)
{
    Node * new_node = new Node;
    new_node -> setdata(val);
    if(this->sizen == 0 )
    {
        //There is empty
        this->first = new_node;
        this->first -> setnext(this->first);
        this->sizen = 1;
    }
    else
    {
     //It's not empty
     Node *node = this->first;
     while(node->getnext()!= this->first)
     {
         node = node->getnext();
     }
     node->setnext(new_node);
     node->getnext() -> setnext(this->first);
     this->sizen +=1;
    }
}
void Circular::display()
{
    Node *temp = this->first;
    std::cout<<temp->getdata()<<" ";
    temp = temp->getnext();

   while(temp!=this->first)
   {
       std::cout<<temp->getdata()<<" ";
       temp = temp->getnext();
   }
}
void Circular::removing(int val)
{
    Node *new_node = this->first, *d;
    /*if(new_node->sizen==0)
        return 0;
    if(new_node->sizen==1 && new_node->getdata() == val)
        {free(new_node);
        return 0;
        }*/
    std::cout<<"Removing "<<val<<std::endl;
    while((new_node->getnext())->getdata()!=val)
    {
        new_node = new_node->getnext();
    }
    if((new_node->getnext())->getdata()==val)
    {
    d = new_node->getnext();
    new_node->getnext() ->setnext(d->getnext());
    free(d);
    }
}
int Circular::getsize(){
    Node *temp = this->first;
    int length = 0;
    length++;
   while(temp->getnext()!=this->first)
   {
       temp = temp->getnext();
       length++;
   }
   return length;
}

int main(){
    Circular l;
    int i, n,k;
    std::cout<<"How many participants do you want? ";
    std::cin>>n;
    std::cout<<"Which participant should be killed? (Kth)";
    std:cin>>k;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        l.append(i);

    l.display();
    l.removing(2);
    l.display();

}
```

And Here is where the problem gets me anxious:

```
void Circular::removing(int val)
{
    Node *new_node = this->first, *d;
    /*if(new_node->sizen==0)
        return 0;
    if(new_node->sizen==1 && new_node->getdata() == val)
        {free(new_node);
        return 0;
        }*/
    std::cout<<"Removing "<<val<<std::endl;
    while((new_node->getnext())->getdata()!=val)
    {
        new_node = new_node->getnext();
    }
    if((new_node->getnext())->getdata()==val)
    {
    d = new_node->getnext();
    new_node->getnext() ->setnext(d->getnext());
    free(d);
    }
}
```

I have no error and when I run the program, I want to remove the Second (2) node, but it shows me:
1 1114304 1114304 1114304 1114304 1114304 and so on.

Comment: `new_node->getnext() ->setnext` is kinda pointless, since you destroy `new_node->getnext()` in the very next line. Meanwhile, `new_node->next` is never updated, and becomes dangling once the node is destroyed. In addition, a) if `val` is not in the list, you enter an infinite loop, and b) if `val` happens to be in the first node, you delete the node that `first` points to, but never update `first`, losing the whole list.

Comment: new_node->getnext() ->setnext(d->getnext());  should be    new_node->setnext(d->getnext());

Comment: @AlthafM it worked, i saw right now. Thank you very much! Also I reviewed Igor's opinion and your comment is right, but I wanted just simply to remove one node, without particularly cases. Thanks very much.

Comment: This logic is right for most cases except removing the first node. When you remove first node it may break your linked list functionality because the first pointer will be pointing to some unallocated / deleted location.  Hence it may be worth checking if d == first and then update the first pointer to valid next one.